# How to query Titan Graph Database from iOS App

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, graph, titan, tinkerpop

If I set up a graph-database with an AWS DynamoDB backend using the Titan plug-in, how do I then actually send queries to the database and return values? From this [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeIeY.png) that I found [here](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/blog/tag/Titan), it looks like the TinkerPop API can be used to send these queries. But I can't find any information on running TinkerPop on an iOS device. So how do I interact with the database from the app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TinkerPop and Titan are Java libraries, so if you are writing an IOS app, you should go through the TinkerPop Gremlin Server. As described in the [TinkerPop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#gremlin-server),

> [Gremlin Server] Provides a method for Non-JVM languages (e.g. Python, Javascript, etc.) to communicate with the TinkerPop stack.... By default, communication with Gremlin Server occurs over WebSockets and exposes a custom sub-protocol for interacting with the server.

In your IOS app, you can connect to the Gremlin Server using a WebSockets client library, such as [SocketRocket](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket) (Objective-C) or [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) (Swift). Then you would need to send a `RequestMessage` to the Gremlin Server following the format described in the [TinkerPop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_developing_a_driver). An [initial approach](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/Os7W2ILBxdM/ywXeWaBSEAAJ) to create a Gremlin Driver in Swift has been attempted ([gist](https://gist.github.com/emehrkay/ba42d6fb6e1075308eb7fca96dea9041)).

Alhtough WebSockets is the default connection protocol, you can optionally [configure HTTP](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_connecting_via_rest) on the Gremlin Server instead, then make [HTTP requests](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html) to the server.